# Node.js Oracle Database connection error: Error : TypeError: oracle.getconnection is not a function

Tags: node.js, oracle, selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor

```
export class DBConnect {

  databaseConnection() {
    let connection;
    const oracle = require('oracledb');
    try {
    connection = oracle.getconnection({
      user : 'user',
      password : 'password',
      connectString : 'connectString'
    });
    connection.execute('Select * from table',
    function (err, result) {
     console.log(result.rows);
    });
   } catch 
    (err) {
     console.log('Error :' + err);`enter code here`
    }
  }

}
```

Getting Error

> Error : TypeError: oracle.getconnection is not a function

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/example.js#L32 shows:

```
 connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
```

Seems like you misspelled getconnection with the lowercase c.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to install and import package oracle in your code.

- install oracle package, type in your terminal in root of your file

  npm i oracledb
- type this in top your code

  const oracledb = require('oracledb');